# Intent broadcasted not received by the activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to broadcast Intent between 2 activities.

The Intent is sent from FilterActivity to PreviewActivity as shown below

```
mFiltersView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                CameraFiltersFactory effect = (CameraFiltersFactory) v.findViewById(R.id.filteredImage).getTag();
                final Intent previewIntent = new Intent(FiltersActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);    
                startActivityForResult(previewIntent, 0);

                effect.save(new GPUImage.OnPictureSavedListener() {

                    @Override public void onPictureSaved(Uri uri) {    
                        final Intent ImageIntent = new Intent();
                        ImageIntent.setData(uri);     
                        ImageIntent.setAction("com.test.FILTER_RENDERED");
                        sendBroadcast(ImageIntent);
                    }
                });
```

In the PreviewActivity I need to register the receiver and use an IntentFiter to catch the Intent and check it.

```
public class PreviewActivity extends Activity {

    ReceiveMessages myReceiver = null;
    Boolean myReceiverIsRegistered = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myReceiver = new ReceiveMessages();
        if (!myReceiverIsRegistered) {
            // registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter());
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.test.FILTER_RENDERED"));

            myReceiverIsRegistered = true;
        }
     ....

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if (!myReceiverIsRegistered) {
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.test.FILTER_RENDERED"));
            myReceiverIsRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (myReceiverIsRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
            myReceiverIsRegistered = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Intent mNewIntent = intent;

        Bundle bundle = null;
        String fragment = null;
        if (intent != null) {
            mImagePreviewUri = mNewIntent.getData();
            if(mImagePreviewUri!=null) {
                mCameraActionsView.setEnabled(true);
                mImagePreview.setImageURI(mImagePreviewUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ReceiveMessages extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
             if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.test.FILTER_RENDERED")){
                if (intent != null) {
                    mImagePreviewUri = intent.getData();
                    if(mImagePreviewUri!=null) {
                        mCameraActionsView.setEnabled(true);
                        mImagePreview.setImageURI(mImagePreviewUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the Intent is never received by the activity<

Any idea why, OnReceive is not triggered ?

Answer (score 0):

When the broadcast is sent from your FilterActivity to your PreviewActivity, your BroadcastReceiver in Preview Activity is not yet registered to receive any broadcasts and hence it misses it. A normal broadcast needs the receiver to be registered at the time of broadcast in order for it to be received. It does not stick around and wait for your receiver to get registered.  In your code, the receiver gets registered only after your PreviewActivity comes in foreground i.e. in OnResume method, by then the broadcast is already gone. Also, your receiver is unregistered in onStop i.e. as soon as the PreviewActivity  goes into background. So, while the Preview Activity is not on foreground all subsequent broadcasts are missed till onResume is called again.  If you would have used a StickyBroadcast instead of a normal broadcast the broadcast would have been available and received by your receiver. But there are security implications of StickyBroadcasts lying around because of which it's use is deprecated.

Comment: is there a way to make sure that the new activity is started before sending the intent ? because in my code before sending the broadcast, I start the activity. Pleaas check the updated description

Comment: The registration is done on the onCreate of the activity not on onResume

Comment: Although the receiver is initialized in onCreate(). the registration is being done on both onCreate() and OnResume(). Seeing your code, it looks like there is some design issue. Anyways, to answer your previous question, if you want to pass some information to PreviewActivity why dont you pass it as extras. Create previewIntent inside onPictureSaved add extras to it and startActivityForResult from there ? I dont see the need for sending broadcast.